# jQuery DataTables Server Side Processing - Send Entire Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I currently create a table using an MVC Partial View for each row in the tabel, then initialising the table as a jQuery DataTable.

I am looking at switching to using Server Side processing to allow for larger numbers of records, my research so far indicates this is done by returning a JSON array of data from a method on the server, the data is then rendered into columns using JS.

Is it possible instead to return the actual rows in html (from my partial view) to be shown in the DataTable?

Comment: I think this is not directly supported. It is possible, of course, if you create a JSON with the needed attributes from the HTML received. But why would you do that... I suggest you to post on the official DataTables forum if you really need this functionality and can't manage to make it work. They respond quickly.

Comment: You can pass array of arrays to datatable either..